# How to teleport model to a random box in array?

Tags: roblox, luau

For whatever reason I can't seem to get my model to teleport inside one of the boxes.
Also in workspace it's setup as
Workspace

> > **Folder**
> > script

> **Folder (named boxes)**
> box-box10

```lua
local clickDetector = game.Workspace.Paper.ClickDetector

local HS = script.Parent
local boxFolder = HS.Boxes

boxArray = {

    boxFolder.Box.CFrame,
    boxFolder.Box10.CFrame,
    boxFolder.Box3.CFrame,
    boxFolder.Box4.CFrame,
    boxFolder.Box5.CFrame,
    boxFolder.Box6.CFrame,
    boxFolder.Box7.CFrame,
    boxFolder.Box8.CFrame,
    boxFolder.Box9.CFrame
}


function onMouseClick()

    local baby = game.Workspace.FinalBaby
    local whichBox = boxArray[math.random(1, #boxArray)]
    
    baby:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(whichBox)
end
        
end


clickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(onMouseClick)
```

Comment: Why do you have a second  `end` just chilling out, not connected to anything?

Comment: lil goofy accident

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you never had to use a for loop but just a variable that randomizes everything in the array

```
local clickDetector = game.Workspace.Paper.ClickDetector

local HS = script.Parent
local boxFolder = HS.Boxes

boxArray = {

boxFolder.Box.Part,
boxFolder.Box10.Part,
boxFolder.Box3.Part,
boxFolder.Box4.Part,
boxFolder.Box5.Part,
boxFolder.Box6.Part,
boxFolder.Box7.Part,
boxFolder.Box8.Part,
boxFolder.Box9.Part

}


function onMouseClick()
    
    

    local R = math.random(1, #boxArray)


        local baby = game.Workspace.FinalBaby.PrimaryPart
        local whichBox = boxArray[R]
        
        baby.CFrame = CFrame.new(whichBox.Position)
            
    end




clickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(onMouseClick)
```